# Default owner/permissions of created files via VSFTPD

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, umask

How do I set the default values of directories and files created to be 775 ?  My understanding is that I need to modify the umask on VSFTPD, but how do I know what to change it to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Umask and final permissions that you need should add up to 777. Since you need 775 permissions, you need 777 - 775 = 002 as umask.

Comment: Beware that these are octal values, so `local_umask=002` may not give the expected results — you better prefix by a '0' : `local_umask=0002` (see `man vsftpd.conf`).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou, ``002`` is an octal value, isn't it? Why do you add another leading ``0``?

Comment: Well, it may not matter for `002` (can't remember my needs at the time), but it should for e.g. `022` (which will be treated as base 10 `22`) vs `0022`.  Anyway, it didn't work for me without it…

Answer (score 19):

In case you are wondering where to set your umask, it can be set in the vsftpd config file (/etc/vsftpd.conf) as `anon_umask` for anonymous access and `local_umask` for users.

For the mask to work properly (even without anonymous access) it seems necessary to set `anon_upload_enable=YES` and `anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES`. If these are not set, writing, reading and executing will not be allowed for groups or others on files uploaded via ftp (even though the standard privileges may be set for something else).

In your case, if you need user-authenticated access, you should set the following:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=0002
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0777
```

Here, `file_open_mode` sets the default setting of files. `777` makes it readable, writeable and executable for anyone. With `local_umask` set to `002`, this gives you `775`, as you requested.

Notica that `local_umask` defaults to `077`, disabling groups and others to access files in any way (hence it is set here).

Further reading: https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: How about set to file_open_mode=7777 ?

Comment: and "sudo chmod -R 777 /mysharedpath"

Comment: Thank you brethren for `anon_umask`